# Align itemize items and text in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I have itemize environment in a table. With a text in other cell, the alignment is not correct. How can I shift the text so that the item is aligned with text? Or, how can I control the indentation of items in an itemize environment in general?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\fu}[1]{%
%\tightlist%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]%
#1%
\end{itemize}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[htbp]{l|p{0.6\textwidth}}
    \toprule
\textbf{SB Solution Component} & \textbf{BB Data Satisfied} 
\\\midrule

\textbf{Sensing Data Module} & \fu{
\item Ready Signal
}
\\\midrule

\textbf{Contexts Module} & N/A
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{BB Data Satisfied for SB Solution Component}
  \label{tab:data}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one command line `\leftmargini=xxpt` in your fu macro, as shown here.

```
\newcommand{\fu}[1]{%
\leftmargini=10pt
\begin{itemize}[nosep]%
#1%
\end{itemize}%
```